# How to Select Masters Via Visio VBA

Tags: vba, visio

Is it possible to programmatically change the selected master within a specific stencil document in Visio, using VBA?  If so, how would I go about doing it?

It doesn't seem possible to use the Window.Select method, since that seems to only work in the drawing page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visio API only it is only possible to **get** selected master(s) using the **Window.SelectedMasters** property, but not set it (it is a readonly property).

So, there is no direct solution. 
If you are okay with (sort of) workaround, you can take a look at mine here (the same question):

http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=3378.msg13172#msg13172

It simply sends keyboard keys to the stencil window right number of times :)